# Свой класс, наследуемый от SurfaceView

Tags: android

Здравствуйте.

Предположим, что есть свой класс - пусть Surview, наследуемый от SurfaceView.  Так вот, если делать так в onCreate ативити: `setContentView(new Surview(this));`, то получится, что весь экран заполнен SurfaceView. Мне же нужно, чтоб экран заполнялся layout.xml, в котором есть   
`<SurfaceView ...  id="@id+/surfaceview_id/>`, привязанный к surview.  
 Что-то вроде такого:

`Surview surview = (Surview) findViewById(R.id.surfaceview_id)`.

Но если я сделаю так, то приложение будет крашиться с криком

```
android.view.SurfaceView cannot be cast to (мойPackage.Surview).
```

Подскажите, как провернуть примерно то, что изложено выше?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вставить в xml свой класс вместо SurfaceView

```
<мойPackage.Surview ...  id="@id+/surfaceview_id/>
```

Comment: Теперь такая проблема

>android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #161: Error inflating class мойPackage.Surview

Я так понял, что у меня в классе нет каких-то методов. Как быть с этим?

Comment: @Sharlei, почитать уроки по разработке кастомных View    
https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=android%20custom%20view&es_th=1

Comment: Собственно, вроде разобрался, нужно было в конструкторе класса поступить так, как в первом ответе тут: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2884501/android-custom-view-constructor